# How to build the bias_act_plugin extension for stylegan3

Tags: python, pytorch, ninja, stylegan

I am trying to run the code in [stylegan3](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan3), and I am getting the error

```
RuntimeError: Error building extension 'bias_act_plugin'
```

I looked online for some ideas and [they told me](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan3/issues/124) to install *ninja* with *pip*. I have done that I am still getting the error. How can I to deal with this issue?

My gcc and g++ version is 7.5.0.

Comment: Is this enough information for a reader to help you? I don't use Python, but it seems there is not much here to help someone replicate your error.

Comment: @halfer Do you need anything specific?

Comment: It wouldn't be me, so no - but in my experience, posts this brief tend not to attract answers, mainly because they are not answerable, or readers think they are not answerable. Is there anything more you could add?

Comment: @halfer I can paste the entire error in the terminal. Do you think that would be wise?

Comment: Excellent idea. Stack traces are generally very useful.